# jQuery - disabling select option depends on value from another div field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with disabling some value from `option` field. I try to disable all the values who is less than value from another `div` field. My code looks like this:

```
<div id="cur-hour">09</div>

<select id="time_to_hour" class="select">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

And I have this js code:

```
$(function(){
    if($("#time_from_hour > option").val() < $("#cur-hour").val()) {   
            $('#time_from_hour > option').prop('disabled', true);
        }
});
```

But it didn't work - here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhPp7/36/

Comment: you havent given any html for "time_to_hour"

Comment: it looks exactly the same - it can be deleted from test code - DONE

Comment: The `div` element doesn't have a `.val()`. It has `.text()` or `.html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
var n=parseInt($("#cur-hour").html());    
$("#time_to_hour option").each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) < n ) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhPp7/38/

Answer (score 0):

Your condition won't work because the **`value`** of `option` tag is a **`string.`**

Also `val()` is not used for `divs`, so instead use `.html()` or `.text()`

Also it has to parsed as integer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){
var options = document.getElementById('time_to_hour').options;
var chk = document.getElementById('cur-hour').innerHTML;


for(var o=0;o< options.length;o++)
{
        var va = parseInt(options[o].value);
    if(va!="" && va<chk)
    {
        alert(va);
        options[o].disabled=true;
    }   
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use span to store the value it makes easier to find it.

09

$(function(){

$('#time_to_hour option').each(function () {

```
    if (parseInt($("#index").text()) > parseInt($(this).text())) {
        this.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

});

I hope above code will work out for you...
Here is the working example from your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qhPp7/35/